# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\e xt\php_pgsql.dll

Tags: php, zend-framework

I trying for zend framework but when I create project through command prompt that time following warning is coming the warning is
**PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\e
xt\php_pgsql.dll**

Comment: I don't know Xampp very well, I usually use a LAMP stack. Anyway, this error is pretty straightforward: you need to avoid the load of this extension in your php.ini, or install the required dll if you need PostreSQL

Comment: I guess you better check my answer at the very end! :)
Sorry if that doesn't help you! :/

Answer (score 5):

In My Case, my XAMPP was installed in the following path:

```
C:\xampp
```

And also when I try to run the following command on CMD,

```
any_drive_and_path_here>php phpFile.php
```

It gave me warning error messages like above, more than 15+!!!
(And I had to do the following steps to resolve for each of the warning messages.)
Then I searched the Google. And I got the idea into mind, whatever it is these modules are gonna be loaded, just because that the relevant line for each module in php.ini file has been un-commented (removing the semicolon ";" at the beginning of each line for each relevant module in php.ini file).
And also as the error msg has given I checked if the extention dll file exists in the

```
xampp\php\ext directory.
```

(those extentions were there.)

Then I read the php.ini file instructions which is at the top of that file! :)
It has given the instructions, to modify the path in each extension enabling lines.

**Summary And To-Do :**

In this case, relevant to this warning:
**Tip:**
if your XAMPP is installed in the following path  **"C:\xampp"**  find and modify the following line(lines if you have more warnings than this)

```
From: extension=php_pgsql.dll
To:   extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pgsql.dll
```

And then whenever you start the CMD and try executing the php command, php.ini knows where the exact place your extension.dll file resides in! :)

**Hint:**
 Don't Forget To Read the php.ini file instructions which is at the top! :)

Tested these steps on Windows 8, I assume this works on other old versions too :)

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your `php.ini` the extension `php_pgsql.dll` is being tried to load. But could not be loaded.

Look for lines like `extension=php_pgsql.dll` in your `php.ini` then remove it.

But if you are working [pgsql](/questions/tagged/pgsql) then you need fix the dll or find an alternate extension that works!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify you php.ini file to enable the php_pgsqlsql.dll